# VBA separate two double digit values by a slash in a single cell

Tags: excel, number-formatting, vba

I feel like this should be relatively straight forward, but I cannot seem to find something that works.

I want to be able to separate two values in a VBA macro that are previously defined as values after doing some preliminary calculations. I then want to be able to put both of these values in the same cell, separated by a slash ("/").

Here are two codes I have written by neither seem to get the job done:

```
Sub Macro3()

TotalK = 10
BB = 15

ActiveCell.Value = "=TotalK &""/""& BB"

End Sub
```

The other way I have attempted this (which is extremely inefficient):

```
If TotalK > 9 Then
     wsNew.Range("E45").NumberFormat = "00""/""0": wsNew.Range("E45").Value = TotalK & BB
ElseIf BB > 9 Then
     wsNew.Range("E45").NumberFormat = "0""/""00": wsNew.Range("E45").Value = TotalK & BB
ElseIf TotalK > 9 And BB > 9 Then
     wsNew.Range("E45").NumberFormat = "00""/""00": wsNew.Range("E45").Value = TotalK & BB
Else
     wsNew.Range("E45").NumberFormat = "0""/""0": wsNew.Range("E45").Value = TotalK & BB
End If
```

The second method words, except for when TotalK and BB both exceed 9. The output is 211/7, for example, when it should be 21/17.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find a simple workaround:

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveCell.Value = TotalK & "/" & BB
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this out,

```
Sub Macro3()
TotalK = 10
BB = 15
ActiveCell.Value = TotalK & "/" & BB
End Sub
```